# PHP/MySQL - How to prove that a user has edited a value and not the admin

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP online system with one admin and users. The users have to accept a contract. The acceptance is saved in a MySQL table. Is it possible to store this value in such a way that proves that the user and not the admin has ticked the checkbox? Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Why don't you keep track of the user ids if both a usual user and admin user are going to have them, just put an updated_by column in the table?

Comment: there is still the possibility that as a database administrator I simply manipulate the values in the table. Is this somehow preventable by means of a protocol in order to prove this legally?

Comment: Usually a audit log helps in such a case. But being an admin I can create an entry in that table as well, but it can be a hassle to create an audit log entry manually. 
Alternatively Why not hire an ethical admin? :)

Answer (score 0):

Database logs? Each user has own database account, admin has his own one. In logs you store which data was changed by which user.

You should check [The Binary Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html) which contains data about queries which changes records in your database.

Comment: This seems like a comment. To turn it to answer I would suggest adding where the logs are located by default for `MySql`.

Comment: @kabanus you are right. I hope reference to binary log looks good

Comment: Thank you for the hint! This is absolutely new for me. Can the log also be used to see which users (via their ID in the MYSQL table) change values via the PHP form, or can only MySQL users be logged?

Comment: @user3719643 like you said - you can have admin-cheater so when you use solution with different database accounts for different users is more secure. But you can build your queries in that way that you will store user's ID who modified specified record.

Answer (score 0):

you can store your user type in session when any user/admin logged in. Then when any user ticked the checkbox, you can check that session value & detect whether it's a user or admin.

Comment: There is no way looking at the database to see which session was being used at the time. Also, sessions expire after a short time.

Comment: there is still the possibility that as a database administrator I simply manipulate the values in the table. Is this somehow preventable by means of a protocol in order to prove this legally?